# meson build set verbosity

Tags: meson-build, verbosity

is there a way to decrease the traces output when the project is configured
with meson?

e.g.

**`meson build .....`**

```
$ meson build --reconfigure
The Meson build system
Version: 0.59.1
```

......

```
Executing subproject mylib 

mylib| Project name: mylib
mylib| Project version: 1.0.0
mylib| C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 8.5.0 "cc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-4)")
mylib| C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.30-108
mylib| Build targets in project: 1
mylib| Subproject mylib finished.

Dependency mylib from subproject subprojects/mylib found:
```

Comment: You can turn off `stdout` for a command by adding redirection `&> /dev/null`. So, just do `meson compile builddir &> /dev/null` and you will see no output at all.

Comment: Yes I've done in this way , I wonder if there is a smarter solution